# AutoCompleteTextView with SimpleCursorAdapter return NullPointerException on filtering

Tags: android, android-sqlite, simplecursoradapter, autocompletetextview

I have a AutoCompleteTextView which I have linked with a SimpleCursorAdapter . Everything is working fine , but when user input characters which are not in the database , so the filtering method returns a null cursor. This cause a non-fatal NullPointerException. My code is

```
mAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
        @Override
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
            String partial = null;
            if(constraint!=null)
               partial = constraint.toString();
            Cursor result= dbHelper.readProductCategory(partial);
            return result;
        }
    });
```

Warning  in logcat

```
 W/Filter﹕ An exception occured during performFiltering()!
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.orderoapp.ordero.data.ProductDatabaseHelper.readProductCategory(ProductDatabaseHelper.java:70)
        at com.orderoapp.ordero.OrdersFragment$1.runQuery(OrdersFragment.java:87)
        at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.runQueryOnBackgroundThread(CursorAdapter.java:397)
        at android.support.v4.widget.CursorFilter.performFiltering(CursorFilter.java:50)
        at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:234)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

I don't know what to do in case of null cursor. Should I return null ? What would be the best way to handle this.
Also when user delete the text in the AutoCompleteTextview , I got this error

```
E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
```

Any ideas? I would gladly appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error was due to if statement in the

```
  ProductDatabaseHelper.readProductCategory
```

method. The if condition was

```
if ( con.length() > 0 ) {

        result = getReadableDatabase().query(ProductEntry.TABLE_NAME, projection,
               ....
    }
```

So when con was null , it gives NullPointerException . The solution is very simple . Before checking if con.length() >0 , just check if con is not null.

```
if ( con!=null && con.length() > 0 ) {
...
    }
```